# Logarithm simplification from a double integral question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I solved this integral

$$\int_0^{ln2} \int_{e^y}^2 \frac xydxdy$$

and got this: $$\frac{-\ln(2)^2}8 -\frac{\ln(2)}8  + \frac{3}{16} $$

However, when I checked the answer from the back of the book, the answer appears as

$$\frac{\ln^3(2)}6 $$

Probably, it's very apparent to many people but I couldn't simply down to that. I'd appreciate it if anyone can show me the steps of simplification.

Comment: Well, they aren't equal.

Comment: Does it converges ?. After the $x$-integration, you'll get
$$
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\,2\,\right)}{4 - \mathrm{e}^{2y}  \over y}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$

Comment: Is the integrand supposed to be $\frac{y}{x}$ instead of $\frac{x}{y}$?

Comment: See the edit history for this question.  At some point, someone edited the integrand and wrote $x/y$ instead of the original $y/x$.  As a result, the integral of $x/y$ is not convergent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the book is correct, and has approximate value $$ \frac{\log^3 2}{6} \approx 0.055504108664821579953.$$  Your value is approximately $0.040799975690231658239$, too small.  Indeed, evaluating the inner integral yields $$\int_{x=e^y}^2 \frac{y}{x} \, dx = \left[y \log x \right]_{x=e^y}^2 = y (\log 2 - y).$$  Evaluating the outer integral gives $$\int_{y=0}^{\log 2} y (\log 2 - y) \, dy = \left[\frac{y^2}{2} \log 2 - \frac{y^3}{3} \right]_{y=0}^{\log 2} = \frac{\log^3 2}{2} - \frac{\log^3 2}{3} = \frac{\log^3 2}{6},$$ as claimed.

Comment: It appears that maybe the OP has the incorrect integrand.